# Monitor AWS Direct Connect Virtual Interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-direct-connect

Is there a way to monitor AWS Direct Connect Virtual Interfaces with cloud watch ?

I see DX Metrics for connections, but dont see anything for the virtual interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is no you cant. Cloud watch only monitors physical connections (using DX Metrics).